# Change domain's property after catch(DataIntegrityViolationException) error in delete. Grails 2.5

Tags: grails

I am trying to modify a domain property after catch a error in delete. My action code is as follows:

```
@Transactional
def delete(User userInstance) {

    if (userInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    try {
        userInstance.delete(flush: true)
    }
    catch(e) {
        userInstance.active = false
        userInstance.save(flush: true)
        render status: 200
        return
    }


    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: '${className}'), userInstance.id])
            redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
    }
}
```

I want to change the active property value to false in the event of an error when deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `DataIntegrityViolationException` because you are violating some of the foreign key relationship rules, in your case most probably your `user` instance is referenced by some other domain object(table).

You can do whatever you want on the catch block in your case `userInstance.active = false` is fine, but you are not getting the error because of this (again raising another error from the catch block).